# async.series is not doing things in series. Why?

Tags: javascript, async.js

As I understand it, async.series does things one at a time. Can you help me decipher this output?

The code to manipulate a mongo database collection:

```
    async.series([
        countDocuments(db,function(){console.log("Step 1 complete");}),
        insertDocument(db,function(){console.log("Step 2 complete");}),
        countDocuments(db,function(){console.log("Step 3 complete");}),
        removeDocument(db,function(){console.log("Step 4 complete");}),
        countDocuments(db,function(){
        })], function(){
            db.close();
    });
```

And the output:

```
Step 1 complete
Step 3 complete
Step 2 complete
Step 4 complete
```

This makes no sense to me. Surely the whole point is to wait until 2 is complete before starting 3?

Answer (score 3):

You must pass callback functions to [`async.series`](https://github.com/caolan/async#series). Currently you're just calling all those functions directly - immediately - and pass their results to `async.series`. Also, each of those function does get a `callback` argument from passed from `async` that you need to invoke asynchronously to tell that the step is done and the next one should be executed.

```
async.series([
    function(cb) {
        countDocuments(db,function(e){console.log("Step 1 complete");cb(e);});
    },
    function(cb) {
        insertDocument(db,function(e){console.log("Step 2 complete");cb(e);}),
    },
    function(cb) {
        countDocuments(db,function(e){console.log("Step 3 complete");cb(e);}),
    },
    function(cb) {
        removeDocument(db,function(e){console.log("Step 4 complete");cb(e);}),
    },
    function(cb) {
        countDocuments(db, cb); // the short version
    }
], function(){
    db.close();
});
```

Comment: Tx, I think I get it. For posterity, this generates a Mongo "sockets closed" error from the database, as does Nada's answer. Which I think indicates it is trying to connect to the db once the db.close has already been issued.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing async.series with async.waterfall. Here, your 4 functions will all start regardless of whether earlier functions have finished executing or not. However, the final call back (which executes db.close()) will be called back once all of the series functions have finished executing (It is like a barrier). If you use async.waterfall, every function will pass its result to the next one. which means the first will start and finish then the second will start and finish and so on.

Another issue is, you are not calling the callback by the end of your every function. If you don't call the callback the function which executes db.close() will never get called.